# Creating a master-detail view in windows phone app using json data from web service

Tags: c#, wpf, json, xaml

I want to select a listbox item and show its details on the next page in text blocks. Here is my code. Please help me or give some links to which I could refer... Thanks in advance.

Here is my master page xaml.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstUniversity" Height="582" SelectionMode="Single" FontSize="30"     VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1">
                    <Button Name="btn" Content="{Binding NAME}" Click="click" BorderThickness="1"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="75" Width="460" FontSize="24" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

my c# code for master page

```
public class University
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string RANK { get; set; }
    public string FEES { get; set; }
    public string APPLIEDFEES { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
   try
   {
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mastertionary.com/ios/connect1.php");
      webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new         DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
  webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}     

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<University>>(e.Result);
        lstUniversity.ItemsSource = rootObject;
}

public void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/details.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

My details page xaml is

```
<ListBox x:Name="unidetails" Height="582" SelectionMode="Single" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1">
                    <StackPanel><TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RANK}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FEES}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding APPLIEDFEES}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Please help me how can I display the details such as rank, fees, etc. according to the selected item from the master page?

Comment: why do you have two pages? you can do it in single page

Comment: Pivot page is a lot cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: i want to do it with two pages please guide me with this or tell me some links to refer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can store the object in the PhoneApplicationState and retrieve it in the next page.

   ```
     if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("ApplicationDataObject"))
     {
       // If it exists, assign the data to the application member variable.
       ApplicationDataStatus = "data from preserved state.";
       ApplicationDataObject = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ApplicationDataObject"] as University;
     }
   ```

   Refer: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
2. Alternatively, use a static object which can be refered from both the pages.

   public static University UnivObject;
3. If there are not many parameters, send the data in the query parameters like:
   Say, if you have binded your listbox with a List, you can access the selected item in the listbox Tap event as:

   ```
   University univObj = listbox.SelectedItem;

   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/details.xaml?UID=" + univObj.UID + "&NAME=" + univObj.Name + "&RANK=" + univObj.Rank,UriKind.Relative));
   ```

You can retrieve the values in the next page as:

```
NavigationContext.QueryString["UID"].ToString;
```

Comment: In the 3rd point, how can i pass specific parameters...because the values will change with every selection....rank and name will be according to the name of university i selected in the first page....soo how should i pass variables accordingly?  I am new to this ..please help me to understand

Comment: thanku! one more ques please..if i want to display onlee those names associated with uid then how to use the where clause?

Comment: @user3710436 use filteredList =  listName.Where(ob => ob.UID!=null).ToList();
Please mark the answer if you found it useful. Thanks!